# Enable to reach endpoint 404 error code - Deployed application

Tags: angular, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, quarkus, quarkus-rest-client

I'm deploying my application in the cloud, inside a cluster on 03 pods:

1. one pod: backend - Quarkus
2. one pod: frontend - Angular
3. one pod: DB - Postgres

**The backend has 03 endpoints:**

1. One endpoint: GraphQL
2. Two endpoints: Rest

**The pods are exposed:**

1. backend: ClusterIp
2. DB: ClusterIp
3. frontend: NodePort

**I have an Ngnix web server & 02 ingress manifests; one for the backend and a second for the frontend:**

1- backend-ingress:

```
    apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      name: mcs-thirdparty-back-ingress
      namespace: namespace
      annotations:
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    spec:
      ingressClassName: nginx-internal
      rules:
      - host: backend.exemple.com
        http:
          paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              service:
                name: mcs-thirdparty-backend
                port:
                  number: 8080
            pathType: Prefix
```

2- frontend-ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: mcs-thirdparty-ingress
  namespace: namespace
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx-internal
  rules:
  - host: bilels.exemple.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          service:
            name: mcs-thirdparty-frontend
            port:
              number: 80
        pathType: Prefix
```

For the GraphQL endpoint/request; the frontend can correctly communicate with the backend and fetchs the required data.
When I run the POST request to fetch the accessToken from the server (Rest Endpoint), I receive the 404 error code.

[The error screenshot is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rp4ey.jpg)

I tried to add several changes in the backend-ingress manifest, but always 404
`- path: /(.*)`
`- path: /*`
`- path: /response`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thinks that I managed to make another Diagnotic method wiht the help for Ryan Dawson.
I did PortForaward the backend pod and request from the locally, then I found that there is a 500 error code --> meaning that the request was not matching the api requirements: in the frontend I was sendign the wrong context type.

--> so the ingress config is already in a good shape.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your backend application is providing on port 8080?

If this is true, you should access `backend.exemple.com:8080/response` , supposing that `response` is the name of the path you have configured.

### Enabling swagger-ui to test

You could enable the swagger-ui on your quarkus application to make sure of your endpoints.

To do it, you must add this to your `pom.xml`:

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-openapi</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

And set this on your `application.properties` (to be able to access the swagger-ui when you're not running on dev mode):

```
# If this should be included every time. By default this is only included when the application is running in dev mode.
quarkus.swagger-ui.always-include=true
```

With this done, you can access the swagger-ui at: `your-path:your-port-number/q/swagger-ui`, like `backend.exemple.com:8080/q/swagger-ui`

Comment: Hi @Felipe Windmoller

Comment: Felipe, thank you for the good recommandation !
I thinks that I managed to make another Diagnotic method wiht the help for Ryan Dawson.
I did PortForaward the backend pod and request from the locally, then I found that there is a 500 error code --> meaning that the request was not matching the api requirements: in the frontend I was sendign the wrong context type.